# Generic inner class with instance variable that is an object of another generic inner class

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

First, I realize that I can make `ProblemClass` a non-generic class and not receive a compiler error. I am wondering what this error means though. My code is very simple, a generic class with two private inner classes. The outer class has an instance variable of type `InnerClass<E>` and the inner class `ProblemClass<E>` also has an instance variable of type `InnerClass<E>`. When ProblemClass` is instantiated, all it does is set *o = a*, where *o,a* are the instance variables of the outer class and inner class respectively.

```
public class SuperClass<E> {

    private class InnerClass<E> {
    }

    private class ProblemClass<E> {
        private InnerClass<E> o;

        public ProblemClass() {
            o = a;
        }
    }

    private InnerClass<E> a;
}
```

I receive the following error.

```
SuperClass.java:11: error: incompatible types
            o = a;
                ^
  required: SuperClass<E#1>.InnerClass<E#2>
  found:    SuperClass<E#1>.InnerClass<E#1>
  where E#1,E#2 are type-variables:
    E#1 extends Object declared in class SuperClass
    E#2 extends Object declared in class SuperClass.ProblemClass
1 error
```

My question is, what does this error mean?

Comment: BTW, that isn't a superclass.

Comment: Woops, I guess OuterClass would have been a more appropriate name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply the `E` of `ProblemClass` and the `E` of `InnerClass` are not related - your code is equivalent to

```
public class SuperClass<E> {

    private class InnerClass<F> {
    }

    private class ProblemClass<G> {
        private InnerClass<G> o;

        public ProblemClass() {
            o = a;
        }
    }

    private InnerClass<E> a;
}
```

and you can clearly see that `a` and `o` are not necessarily compatible.

Answer (score 1):

As the error is trying to tell you, you have two different `E`s that may be two different types.

What would happen if you create a `new OuterClass<Integer>.ProblemClass<String>()`?

Comment: So if my inner class contains instance variables that are generic but the types are always going to match the generic type of of the outer class, I can avoid generic inner classes?

Comment: @user2921933 Yes you can.

Comment: @user2921933 - The game changes when one of the inners is `static`, then you **do** have to specify them.

Answer (score 0):

@IanRoberts has the answer, some of your `E` are not the same.

Here's a *fixed* version of your code:

```
public class SuperClass<SE> {

  private class InnerClass<IE> {
  }

  private class ProblemClass<PE> {
    private InnerClass<SE> o;

    public ProblemClass() {
      o = a;
    }

  }

  private InnerClass<SE> a;
}
```